# How do I know the current width of system scrollbar?

Tags: c#, winforms

As you know, one can customize the width of the scrollbar width in Display Properties -> Appearance -> Advanced -> Item: ScrollBar. The default value is 17. However, I can't assume this is always the case, is it possible for me to retrieve this value?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Look at the `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation` class members: [`HorizontalScrollBarHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.horizontalscrollbarheight.aspx) and [`VerticalScrollBarWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.verticalscrollbarwidth.aspx).

Answer (score 36):

Vertical Scroll Bar Width

```
System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to know the size of a `ScrollableControl` minus the size of the scroll bar, the easiest way is to use the `Control.ClientSize` property.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets the height and width of the client area of the control.
>   The client area of a control is the bounds of the control, **minus the nonclient elements such as scroll bars**, borders, title bars, and menus.

Comment: Unfortunately, ClientSize also includes the width of the scrollbar (yields same value as ActualWidth). Doesn't make sense though.

Answer (score 2):

Skip the ClientSize property of the control.  At least in VS2013 the Scrollbar is included in the ClientSize.

When I formatted a RichTextBox with a width of 304 and a vertical scrollbar, the Client Size width was 300, which only accounted for the borders.

stick with the System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth to get your scrollbar width.