# Is it possible to change the scrollbar width in windows gadgets?

Tags: windows, scrollbar, windows-desktop-gadgets

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a thinner scrollbar for my windows gadget.

I am already using these attributes to change the scrollbar colors:

```
    scrollbar-face-color: #EEEEEE;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #CCCCCC;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #AAAAAA;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #000000;
    scrollbar-track-color: #EEEEEE;
```

I was hoping that since the gadget seems to be using the IE rendering engine in quirks mode, there is some option to specify the gadget width?

I guess, if this is not possible, I could use some sort of jQuery plugin that imitates a scrollbar and allows for more customization...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to actively change the width without developing your own control. The scrollbar width is a system wide setting, not an application dependent one.  You can identify how wide it is though with: System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;

Change Scrollbar information:
http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/9516/37132.aspx

Identify Scrollbar Information:
[How do I know the current width of system scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856917/how-do-i-know-the-current-width-of-system-scrollbar)