# How to get AutoScroll scrollbar thickness?

Tags: c#, winforms, vertical-scrolling, autoscroll

I'm working on a program feature in which a FlowLayoutPanel (whose flow direction is set to TopDown) should adjust its width based on whether or not the vertical scrollbar is visible on the screen. I have figured out how to detect if the scrollbar is visible.

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to find the width of the (pre-programmed) vertical scrollbar. The reason that I want to expand the panel's width when it overflows is because the scrollbar overlaps the controls in the panel.

If possible, I'd like to avoid changing the margin/padding of the controls, and I would like to avoid using constants that I declare myself in my code.

I'd also like to avoid adding a VerticalScrollBar component, unless there is an easy way to programmatically scroll through the overflown panel based on the scrollbar's thumb position.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about Winforms?

Comment: WPF or windows forms ? Both have a flowlayoutpanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is different depending on windows forms and WPF.

- For Forms see : [How do I know the current width of system scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856917/how-do-i-know-the-current-width-of-system-scrollbar)

`System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation` class members: [`HorizontalScrollBarHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.horizontalscrollbarheight.aspx) and [`VerticalScrollBarWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.verticalscrollbarwidth.aspx).

- For WPF see : [How to find Vertical Scrollbar width of a Scrollviewer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701760/how-to-find-vertical-scrollbar-width-of-a-scrollviewer-in-c-sharp)

`SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth`

Comment: Thank you Philip! The links you posted were very helpful.